# How to use pl/pgSQL to handle 'comma separated list' returns?

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I'am trying `UNION ALL` many tables into a new table.The columns of the old tables are the same, but the order of the columns is different, so the below SQL statement will get wrong result:

```
CREATE TABLE sum_7_2018_xia_weijian
AS
(
        SELECT * FROM huiwen
        UNION
        SELECT * FROM penglai
        UNION
        SELECT * FROM baoluo
        UNION
        SELECT * FROM dongge
        UNION
        SELECT * FROM resultdonglu
        UNION
        SELECT * FROM resultwencheng
        UNION
        SELECT * FROM tan_illeg
);
```

I finally corrected it, but the SQL statements is too redundant:

step 1. get column names of one of the old tables named `huiwen`

```
SELECT string_agg(column_name, ',')
                FROM information_schema.columns
                WHERE table_schema = 'public' AND table_name   = 'huiwen';
```

results:

```
>                                      string_agg                                     
> ----------------------------------------------------------------------
>
>  gid,id,geom,sxm,sxdm,sxxzqdm,xzqhdm,xzmc,sfzgjsyd,sfkfbj,sfjbnt,sfld,sflyhx,sfhyhx
```

step 2. union tables as a new table. I copy the `string_agg` of table `huiwen` to each SELECT-UNION to keep the order of columns, this is clumsy.

```
CREATE TABLE sum_2018_xia_weijian
AS
(
        SELECT gid,id,geom,sxm,sxdm,sxxzqdm,xzqhdm,xzmc,sfzgjsyd,sfkfbj,sfjbnt,sfld,sflyhx,sfhyhx
        FROM huiwen
        UNION ALL
        SELECT gid,id,geom,sxm,sxdm,sxxzqdm,xzqhdm,xzmc,sfzgjsyd,sfkfbj,sfjbnt,sfld,sflyhx,sfhyhx
        FROM penglai
        UNION ALL
        SELECT gid,id,geom,sxm,sxdm,sxxzqdm,xzqhdm,xzmc,sfzgjsyd,sfkfbj,sfjbnt,sfld,sflyhx,sfhyhx
        FROM baoluo
);
```

results:

```
> Query returned successfully: 2206 rows affected, 133 msec execution time.
```

I tried to do some optimization by `pl/pgSQL` using `Declarations` of variable to handle column names, but failed to find any SQL data type can handle this. Using of `RECORD` result `Pseudo-Types ERROR`：

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION ct() RETURNS RECORD AS $$
DECLARE
    clms RECORD;
BEGIN
    SELECT column_name INTO clms
        FROM information_schema.columns
        WHERE table_schema = 'public' AND table_name = 'huiwen';
    RETURN clms;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
CREATE TABLE sum_2018_xia_weijian
AS
(
    SELECT ct() FROM huiwen
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ct() FROM penglai
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ct() FROM baoluo
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ct() FROM dongge
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ct() FROM resultdonglu
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ct() FROM resultwencheng
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ct() FROM tan_illeg
);
```

Comment: How are you planning to maintain the order of each column in the final select queries?

Comment: @KaushikNayak In the `SELECT-UNION` statements. the order of columns is same between each table.

Comment: But, `string_agg` may not give you the same order of columns for all tables without an explicit order by` If you use an order by column_name in string_agg, then `gid` may not come as the first column, it will be `geom`.

Comment: Yeah，so I copy the `string_agg` to each `SELECT-UNION` to keep the order of columns, but this is clumsy. I just added my code  pl/pgSQL solution which failed by data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `STRING_AGG` twice for getting the `UNION ALL`. You can get all the columns in specific order by explicitly ordering it by `column_name` in the `string_agg`.

Here's a generic function which takes an array of tables and a final table name.

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION fn_create_tab(tname_arr TEXT[], p_tab_name TEXT) 
RETURNS VOID AS $$
DECLARE
l_select TEXT;
BEGIN
   select STRING_AGG(query,' UNION ALL ' ) INTO l_select
    FROM
    (
     SELECT 'select ' || string_agg( column_name,','
     ORDER BY column_name ) || ' from ' || table_name as query
       FROM information_schema.columns
      WHERE table_schema = 'public' AND table_name = ANY (tname_arr)
     GROUP BY table_name
     ) s;

 IF l_select IS NOT NULL
  THEN
    EXECUTE format ('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS %I',p_tab_name);
    EXECUTE format ('create table %I  AS %s',p_tab_name,l_select);
  END IF;    
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Now, run the function like this:

```
select fn_create_tab(ARRAY['huiwen','penglai'],'sum_2018_xia_weijian');
```

Comment: you save my day, @KaushikNayak. I tested the function and it works fine! But I need time to totally understand it...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of making the programming block complex you can follow some below concepts from the documentation of Union or Union All as it says :

1. The number of columns in all queries must be the same.
2. The corresponding columns must have the compatible data type.
3. **The column names of the first query determine the column names of the combined result set.**
4. The GROUP BY and HAVING clauses are applied to each individual query, not the final result set.
5. The ORDER BY clause is applied to the combined result set, not within the individual result set.

By following the 3rd point make your Union query adjusted to refer to the table whose column order is expected in the result.

Comment: sorry @Rizwan, In fact, the dfferent columns order of old tables make error `UNION` results.